# Is it possible to create a fade-in effect for an image that shows up on canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an image (arrow) that shows up when the user interacts with an object on canvas. This image (arrow) tells the user in which direction to drag the object in. Is it possible to create a fade-in effect for the image ?

Here's the code

```
   var curvedArrow = new Image();
    curvedArrow.src = "img/curvedArrow.png";
// curvedArrow.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(curvedArrow, 15, 45, 35, 30);
//  };
```

NOTE: I call the drawImage() without onload, as the image didn't show up on canvas if I called drawImage within onload

Answer (score 1):

Set the `src` after the `.onload` listener, that way it will fire regardless.

```
   var curvedArrow = new Image();
   curvedArrow.addEventListener('load', function() {
        context.drawImage(curvedArrow, 15, 45, 35, 30);
   });
   curvedArrow.src = "img/curvedArrow.png";
```

Then you can use an interval and [globalAlpha](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-alpha-tutorial/) to fade the image in:

```
   var curvedArrow = new Image();
   curvedArrow.addEventListener('load', function() {
        context.globalAlpha = 0;
        var imgFadeInter = setInterval(function(){
           clearContext(); // a function that clears the canvas
           context.globalAlpha += 0.01;
           context.drawImage(curvedArrow, 15, 45, 35, 30);
           if(context.globalAlpha == 1){ 
               clearInterval(imgFadeInter); 
           }
        }, 16); // 16ms because jQuery says so         
   });
   curvedArrow.src = "img/curvedArrow.png";
```

Comment: I tried setting the .src after the onload, but that still didn't make the image object load. In regards to clearContext() function, do I need to clear everything on canvas ? something like context.reset() ?

Comment: you need to clear every frame or the frames just overlap. I recommend clearRect

Comment: I updated my answer in regards to the onload issue. In jQuery I use `$(img).on('load', ...` and forgot that `.onload` is not the equivalent.

Comment: curvedArrow loading is still a no go. I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined "